# What is the reason behind hanuman's brahmacharya?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, brahmacharya

I don't have much details but have a straight question about the celibacy of hanuman. Is there any specific reason that hanuman is brahmachari other than that he is true devotee of lord ram and don't want any distraction from serving the lord ram.